# My images are not showing in my localhost

Tags: html, css, localhost

I did the following steps:

1. Installed Node.js
2. in cmd, write: npm install http-server -g
3. cd user/me/local where my website files are
4. in google chrome, type: localhost:8080

in localhost8080 I open my html file to see how my website looks. All the images are gone.
In my html file I wrote: `<img  src="imagens/karla.jpg" />` 
But I guess my C drive can't be acessed
so not images are show.
I tried `<img  src="http://localhost:8080/imagens/karla.jpg" />` but still doesn't work. However the link http://localhost:8080/imagens/karla.jpg work and the image is there.

Note: when I run Visual Studios to test my website, it works fine. My localhost8080:
[image]

EDIT: Well... everything is working fine guys, is that my dark mode extension in chrome made all my images black... sorry

Comment: Have you got a skeleton of what your directory looks like? Otherwise we’d be guessing

Comment: I added a picture in my post. Is that want you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an "inspect element" by pressing ctrl+shift+i. Then go to sources in the developer console. There you can check the image extension